Rim light for 2D PNG character
How can I add a rim light to a transparent png sequence of my character. I also want to add a very thin outline. I want to use nodes to do this but im new to it so i need some help. I cant use After Effects or similar. I need a node setup (even if its complex) See my character image
Here is my desired effect. If someone could show me node setup that would be perfect as im new to working with nodes. THANKS!
